# How can I use Material UI with Electron React Boilerplate?

Tags: reactjs, electron, material-ui

**Context**

New electron user here. I just cloned and installed the recommended React + Electron repo: https://github.com/electron-react-boilerplate/electron-react-boilerplate

Now I want to use Material-UI. So I thought I just follow the instructions here:

https://material-ui.com/getting-started/installation/

After I did this, the app doesn't show me anything from Material-UI. I created a Component with a simple App Bar. But it does show nothing.

So I found out that there is another package.json in the folder `/app/package.json` 
I cd'd into it and redid the installation. Restart the dev server but still nothing shows up (no appbar, just white screen).

Here is a screenshot: [image]

Also according to the docs I should add a link for the roboto font to the `html` file. Where is this supposed to go? I put it into the only html file I found in `app/app.html`.

**How can one set up Material-UI with Electron or rather this specific boilerplate?**

I couldn't find anything up to date for this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the error. Turns out I imported `MenuIcon` but `material` doesn't export it. So when I get rid of it, the appbar renders correctly.